# Prove I know a value $v$ in a Pedersen Commitment without revealing it

Tags: elliptic-curves, zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments

Given a Pedersen Commitment:

$P = aG + vH$

Where $G$ and $H$ are points in some group. $a$ is a blinding value/mask and $v$ is the value I wish to commit to.

Is there a way to prove I know $v$ without revealing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This extension of the Schnorr protocol would appear to work:

$P := aG + vH$

$\operatorname{GenProof}(a, v)$:

1. $x, y \leftarrow Z_q$
2. $P' := xG + yH$
3. $t  := RandomOracle(P')$  (alternatively, the verifier picks $t$ after learning $P'$)
4. $x' := x + ta, y' := y + tv$
5. return $(P', x', y')$

$\operatorname{Verify}(P, P', x', y')$:

1. $t := RandomOracle(P')$
2. accept if $x'G + y'H = P' + tP$

Comment: Is this more of a proof stating that I know a tuple (a,v) that make P? I think my original question may be impossible, because pedersen commitments are not perfectly hiding. I like this proof though extending it from n=1 excluding the blinder, to n=m scalar, I can prove that I know all m values in a given pedersen commitment plus the blinder. Very cool! If I'm understanding correctly that is :D

Comment: @WeCanBeFriends: to prove you know $a$, you also need to prove that you know $v$.  After all, for any $a'$, there exists a $v'$ with $P = a'G + v'H$.  And, Pedersen commitments *are* perfectly hiding (in fact, because of the existance of $v'$)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple zero knowledge proofs to solve this problem (for example Bulletproofs which are quite efficient but very complicated so I will describe a simpler scheme below. I actually don't know anymore where I saw this scheme so I can't provide any references or security proofs.

$\operatorname{GenProof}(a, v)$:

1. $r \leftarrow Z_q$
2. $P' := rG + vH$ so that $A := P - P' = (aG + vH) - (rG + vH) = (a-r)G$
3. Use a normal signature scheme like EcDSA to sign an empty message for $A$.
4. return $(P', \text{signature})$

$\operatorname{Verify}(P, P', \text{signature})$:

1. $A = P - P'$
2. return $\operatorname{signature\_verify}(\text{signature}, A, \text{empty_message})$

EDIT: I just came up with a very trivial attack on this scheme, DO NOT USE IT.

$\operatorname{Attack}(P)$:

1. $a \leftarrow Z_q$, $A := aG$
2. $P' = P + A$
3. Proceed as usual

Comment: the message is signed with a-r ? How does this prove that I know the v s.t. P = aG + vH?

Comment: Yeah, I just had the same idea, it does not proof anything at all. Will edit my post and try to find the source of the proof.

Comment: @VincBreaker, we are waiting for your feedback on looking for the source that inspired your sketch above. Anyway, you already gave us a lot of tips here...

Comment: @McFly Sadly, I wasn't able to find it anymore, so I also really would like to know where it came from. I remember the paper being about another zero-knowledge proof of some kind which required proofing the knowledge $(a, v)$ at some point but I can't give anymore information. If someone comes across this paper, feel free to let us know :) EDIT: Actually there is some more information: I read it arround a year ago so it has to be at least a year old, but I read a lot about ZKP's a year ago :/